# MySQL Sum and GroupBy in same query

Tags: mysql

I need some help designing a MySQL query that will return the sum of the AMT for each TYPE, grouped by YEAR.  I'm sure this will be easy for someone.  Just not for me!  Thanks.

```
AMT YEAR  TYPE 
10  2010    A 
20  2010    B 
30  2010    B 
20  2011    A 
15  2011    A 
11  2011    B 
15  2011    A 
13  2012    A 
15  2012    A 
20  2012    B 
10  2012    B
10  2012    B 
13  2012    B 
17  2013    A 
22  2013    A 
24  2013    B 
15  2013    B 
20  2013    A 
15  2013    A 
11  2013    B 
15  2013    A 
13  2010    B 
15  2010    A 
20  2010    B 
10  2011    A 
10  2011    A 
13  2011    B 
17  2011    A 
22  2012    A
```

Comment: It is a little unclear what you actually want. From the description it looks like you want sum of AMT grouped by year and type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Amt), Year, Type
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Year, Type
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85415/1)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, especially for the SQL fiddle.

Comment: @DanielAttard -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

you mean

```
select SUM(AMT) from table group by year, type
```

?

this will result in

2011 A X1
2011 B Y1
2012 A X2
2012 B Y2

etc...